# How to display values from lists in a UI QML (QT) inside a Repeater

Tags: c++, list, qt, qml, repeater

I've been facing this issue for days without coming to a conclusion, I hope someone could give me some useful hints to solve it.

I'll try to simplify the issue with an example:

- In my C++ code I defined the class **MyObjectModel** that will act
  later as a model in the **Repeater** block in my main *ui.qml* file.
  MyObjectModel is visible to the QQmlApplicationEngine.
- **MyObjectModel**
  has 2 attributes (lists) : xCoordinatesList and yCoordinatesList.
  They represent the x and y pixel coordinates of a list of points.
  I.e. xCoordinatesList = [100, 200], yCoordinatesList = [10, 20] mean logically that I have 2 points with the following pixel coordinates that I want to display on the screen: (100,10), (10,20).
- The xCoordinatesList and yCoordinatesList are **Roles** of my model
  for the **QML engine**.  This means for instance that in a common
  .qml file i can clearly print the content of xCoordinatesList by
  typing:

  ```
  Component.onCompleted
  {
      console.log("x coordinates: ",xCoordinatesList);
  }
  ```

**The question is: how can I display at the same time the list of points on the screen?**

If I want to display only one dot (so one couple of coordinates) my code works. I really don't know how to extend it to make it print all of them.

In my **MainForm.ui.qml** I defined a **Repeater** inside a **Rectangle** :

```
Rectangle
 {
 ....
            Repeater
        {
            model: dotModel

             delegate:
                 DotItem
                 {
                 id: dotItem;
                 objectName: "dotItem";
                 DotPositionOnMap
                 {
                     id: dotPositionId;
                     objectWidth: dotItem.width;
                     objectHeight: dotItem.height;
                 }
                 x: dotPositionId.xPositionOnMap;
                 y: dotPositionId.yPositionOnMap;
                 }
         }
....
}
```

I need a Repeater because **MyObjectModel** which holds the two lists of x and y coordinates can dynamically change over time.
**dotModel** is just a fake model I use for an other purpose.
**DotItem**  is my qml Item that identifies the red dot circle image I want to depict on the screen for each couple of elements in xCoordinatesList, yCoordinatesList.

**DotItem.ui.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item
{
    width:  10
    height: 10
    opacity: 1
    Image
    {
      id: dotItemImage
      anchors.fill: parent
      source: "red_dot.png"
    }   
}
```

*red_dot.png* image should be displayed for each point depicted on the screen.

**DotPositionOnMap.qml** is responsible for computing the right *x* and *y* pixel position on the screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import "calcCurrentPos_script.js" as CurrentPos

Item
{
// Values filled from MainForm.ui.qml
property int objectWidth
property int objectHeight

// Getting current coordinates
// Fetching element 0 from both lists
property real currentx: CurrentPos.getCurrentxPoint(0);
property real currenty: CurrentPos.getCurrentyPoint(0);

// Generating the x and y pixel position on map.
// Toy example
property int xPositionOnMap : currentx-(objectWidth/2);
property int yPositionOnMap : currenty-(objectHeight/2);
}
```

Where **calcCurrentPos_script.js**

```
function getCurrentxPoint(val)
{
    return xCoordinatesList[val];
}

function getCurrentyPoint(val)
{
    return yCoordinatesList[val];
}
```

In this way I can only display one dot on the screen since I specify in **DotPositionOnMap.qml** which point to fetch:

```
// Fetching element 0 in this case
property real currentx: CurrentPos.getCurrentxPoint(0);
property real currenty: CurrentPos.getCurrentyPoint(0);
```

I used javascript for this attempt because I thought I could use a *for loop* to scan all the elements to be displayed, but it didn't work.

**Extract of my model**

```
QVariant MyModelObject::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    const MyModelObject& object = objects.values().value(index.row());
    ....
    if(role == XRole)
    {
    QList<TrackPoint> tkrList = object.getList();
    QList<QVariant> tkrVariantList;
    for(auto track: trackpointList)
        {
        tkrVariantList.append(track.getPosition().getX());
        }

    return QVariant(tkrVariantList);
    }
    else if(role == YRole)
    {
    QList<TrackPoint> tkrList = object.getList();
    QList<QVariant> tkrVariantList;
    for(auto track: trackpointList)
        {
        tkrVariantList.append(track.getPosition().getY());
        }
    return QVariant(tkrVariantList);
    }
}

....
....
QHash<int, QByteArray> MyModelObject::roleNames() const
{
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
  roles[XRole]        = "xCoordinatesList";
  roles[YRole]      = "yCoordinatesList";
  return roles;
}
```

I truly appreciate any ideas concerning the generalisation of this implementation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** SOLVED ***

In your **main.qml** you can have something like this, which handles the global drawing routine.

```
    Repeater
    {
        model: dotModel
        delegate:
        DotPositionOnMap{}
    }
```

**DotPositionOnMap.qml** will read the list of x and y coordinates and for each element of both will create a dot Item object which will be displayed on the screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item
{

id: dotPositionOnMap
objectName: "dotoPositionOnMap"

Component.onCompleted:
{
 // yCoordinatesList would have given the same result
 var dotListLength = xCoordinatesList.length;

// Dot properties can by handled dynamically
var dotWidth = 5;
var dotHeight = 5;
var dotRadius = 10;
var dotColor = "red"

// For each entry of xCoordinatesList and yCoordinatesList
// I generate a DotShape qml object that will display a dot on the screen
for(var i = 0; i < dotListLength; i++)
{

    var currentXValue = xCoordinatesList[i];
    var currentYValue = yCoordinatesList[i];
    // x and y pixrl values for a DotShape.qml instance
    var xPositionOnMap = currentXValue-(dotWidth/2);
    var yPositionOnMap = currentYValue-(dotHeight/2);

    // Creating DotShape.qml component
    var comp = Qt.createComponent("DotShape.qml");

    var dotComponent = comp.createObject(dotPositionOnMap,
                                           {
                                               "x": xPositionOnMap,
                                               "y": yPositionOnMap,
                                               "width": dotWidth,
                                               "height": dotHeight,
                                               "color": dotColor,
                                               "radius": dotRadius
                                           });
} // end for
} // end script
} // end Item
```

Finally **DotShape.qml** , which's just a small red dot plotted at x,y coordinate

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Rectangle
{ 
// Other properties are generated at runtime
id: dotShapeId;
objectName: "dotShapeId";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt documentation is very clear. The first you have to read is [that article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html). I think that in your case the simpliest way is [list-based model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model). Or, of cource, you can subclass [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html).

Your question is not so clear and you didn't provide the code of your model but maybe this small example will help you:

**Declaration**

```
    class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        enum PointRoles {
                  XRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
                  YRole
              };
        MyModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
        QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

    private:
        QList<QPoint> m_list;
    };
```

**Implementation**

```
MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MyModel::roleNames() const {
     QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
     roles[XRole] = "xcoord";
     roles[YRole] = "ycoord";
     return roles;
 }

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_list.count();
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == XRole)
        return m_list[index.row()].x();
    else if(role == YRole)
        return m_list[index.row()].y();

    return QVariant();
}
```

**Registation**

```
qmlRegisterType<MyModel>("qt.test", 1, 0, "PointModel");
```

**Usage**

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 800
    PointModel {id: mymodel}
    Repeater {
        model: mymodel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: 100 + xcoord
            y: 100 + ycoord
            width: 20
            height: 20
            color: "red"
            radius: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi follbis, first of all thank you for your reply.
Your implementation looks exactly like mine.
I edited my question including my model. 
As you can see there I am returning the list of X and Y points.

I am struggling because x: and y: (in delegate:Rectangle) cannot handle a list of points like *xcoord* and *ycoord* but only a simple int or float. Do you agree? Thx again

Comment: There is no problem to return QPoint instead of int

Comment: Yes, but the problem is to handle a list of QPoints instead of a single one.

x: and y: properties seem not to handle a list.

< http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#x-prop >

Comment: I didn't exactly understand that. Assuming  `MyModel::data()` returns QPoint, is `x: point.x; y: point.y` is what you want to achieve? A model handles list but `data()` should return only single item from the list.

Comment: Hi folibis, what I want to achieve is slightly different. 
**For each instance (mymodel)** of MyModel I would like to display a list of related points **at the same time**. 
i.e. : mymodel1 has these related points (1,2), (3,4)
       mymodel2 has these ones (5,6), (7,8), (9,9) and so on.


My impression now is that for each mymodel instance I can display only 1 point.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Ok, in other words, you want `data()` will return `QList<QPoint>`, right?

Comment: If there's an easy way to draw QList<QPoint> in QML, yes. 
What I'm currently doing is exposing xCoordinatesList and yCoordinatesList from C++ to QML and it works.  
So xCoordinatesList can be something like: [5,7,9] and yCoordinatesList: [6,8,9].
I can clearly log these arrays on a qml file but I'm not able to use them!

Would it be simpler exposing  QList<QPoint> from C++ to QML?
Which block should I use to draw all the points in the list at the same time?

I think that QList<QPoint> is exposable in C++ since:
QPoint can be QVariant and QList<QVariant> can be QVariant it self. Thx